# Nested dictionary path find by value

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am using recursion to find some tree path of specific value from a nested JSON. For example, on the given JSON I am trying to find a full path tree for the **src** element. **Note I have 2 src elements with the same value**, my current code works fine for different **src** values but when I have the same value for **src** key, the result is not expected.

**Current JSON:**

```
{
  "imagepanel": {
    "image": [
      {
        "scaled_image": {
          "classes": "w-full",
          "aspect_ratios": "frame sm:4:3 xmed:4:3",
          "art_directions": [
            {
              "alt": "River waves",
              "src": "path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg",
              "type": "jpg",
              "media": "(min-width:900.1px)",
              "sizes": "50vw",
              "intrinsicwidth": "1411",
              "intrinsicheight": "1000"
            },
            {
              "alt": "River waves",
              "src": "path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg",
              "type": "jpg",
              "media": "(max-width:900px)",
              "sizes": "100vw",
              "intrinsicwidth": "0",
              "intrinsicheight": "0"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "title": "<p><span class=\"drop-cap\" drop-cap=\"true\">WHAT TO WATCH</span></p>",
    "cta_label": "SEE THE LIST",
    "left_image": true
  }
}
```

**Current Code:**

```
import json
import pprint
def breadcrumb_finder(json_dict_or_list, value):
    if json_dict_or_list == value:
        return [json_dict_or_list]
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, dict):
        for k, v in json_dict_or_list.items():
            child = breadcrumb_finder(v, value)
            if child:
                return [k] + child
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, list):
        lst = json_dict_or_list
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            child = breadcrumb_finder(lst[i], value)
            if child:
                return [str(i)] + child

data = r'''{"imagepanel":{"image":[{"scaled_image":{"classes":"w-full","aspect_ratios":"frame sm:4:3 xmed:4:3","art_directions":[{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(min-width:900.1px)","sizes":"50vw","intrinsicwidth":"1411","intrinsicheight":"1000"},{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(max-width:900px)","sizes":"100vw","intrinsicwidth":"0","intrinsicheight":"0"}]}}],"title":"<p><span class=\"drop-cap\" drop-cap=\"true\">WHAT TO WATCH</span></p>","cta_label":"SEE THE LIST","left_image":true}}'''
data = json.loads(data)

all_src = ['path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
for src in all_src:
    nested_path = breadcrumb_finder(data, src)
    print(nested_path)
```

**Current Output:**

```
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '0', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '0', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']

                                                               ^^^ note index here
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '0', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '1', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']

                                                               ^^^ note index here
```

Comment: I am a little confused here, why should the index by 1, if the same src that is being searched is found initially? Or do you want to simply skip over an index if it was already found?

Comment: how about remove the element that already found?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle I agree with you, but my requirement is to find all the paths for the given src value. so if the src is found on multiple places I need those multiple paths :)

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer seems a good idea but not sure how to do that efficiently on larger nested dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit debugging I notice that the problem lies in this piece of code:

```
elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, list):
    lst = json_dict_or_list
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        child = breadcrumb_finder(lst[i], value)
        if child:
            return [str(i)] + child
```

Since you call return when `child` array is not empty, It will also ignore all the element after `lst[i]` if the condition is satisfied.

Therefore I changed your code a little bit by using backtracking:

```
import json
import pprint
results = []
def breadcrumb_finder(json_dict_or_list, value, path, result):
    if json_dict_or_list == value:
        path.append(json_dict_or_list)
        result.append(path.copy())
        path.pop()
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, dict):
        for k, v in json_dict_or_list.items():
            path.append(k)
            child = breadcrumb_finder(v, value, path, result)
            path.pop()
                
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, list):
        lst = json_dict_or_list
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            path.append(i)
            child = breadcrumb_finder(lst[i], value, path, result)
            path.pop()       

data = r'''{"imagepanel":{"image":[{"scaled_image":{"classes":"w-full","aspect_ratios":"frame sm:4:3 xmed:4:3","art_directions":[{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(min-width:900.1px)","sizes":"50vw","intrinsicwidth":"1411","intrinsicheight":"1000"},{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(max-width:900px)","sizes":"100vw","intrinsicwidth":"0","intrinsicheight":"0"}]}}],"title":"<p><span class=\"drop-cap\" drop-cap=\"true\">WHAT TO WATCH</span></p>","cta_label":"SEE THE LIST","left_image":true}}'''
data = json.loads(data)

all_src = ['path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
for src in all_src:
    breadcrumb_finder(data, src, [], results)
    print(results)
```

This will ensure that the list will be iterated all the way.
And the result:

```
[['imagepanel', 'image', 0, 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', 0, 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg'], ['imagepanel', 'image', 0, 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', 1, 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']]
```

Edit: I update the global variable `results` so that it won't be confused with the local variable

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import pprint
def breadcrumb_finder(json_dict_or_list, value):
    if json_dict_or_list == value:
        return [json_dict_or_list]
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, dict):
        for k, v in json_dict_or_list.items():
            child = breadcrumb_finder(v, value)
            if child:
                return [k] + child
    elif isinstance(json_dict_or_list, list):
        lst = json_dict_or_list
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            child = breadcrumb_finder(lst[i], value)
            if child:
                if child[0] != "src" or str(i) not in found_srcs:
                    found_srcs.append(str(i))
                    return [str(i)] + child

data = r'''{"imagepanel":{"image":[{"scaled_image":{"classes":"w-full","aspect_ratios":"frame sm:4:3 xmed:4:3","art_directions":[{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(min-width:900.1px)","sizes":"50vw","intrinsicwidth":"1411","intrinsicheight":"1000"},{"alt":"River waves","src":"path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg","type":"jpg","media":"(max-width:900px)","sizes":"100vw","intrinsicwidth":"0","intrinsicheight":"0"}]}}],"title":"<p><span class=\"drop-cap\" drop-cap=\"true\">WHAT TO WATCH</span></p>","cta_label":"SEE THE LIST","left_image":true}}'''
data = json.loads(data)

all_src = ['path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
found_srcs = []
for src in all_src:
    nested_path = breadcrumb_finder(data, src)
    print(nested_path)
```

By storing the found srcs, you can skip over them. I found that the easiest way is just before adding the src number, you can check and skip that iteration entirely as in the code.

Output:

```
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '0', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
['imagepanel', 'image', '0', 'scaled_image', 'art_directions', '1', 'src', 'path/to/file/53339c03d67e6ee5-lesson-3.jpg']
```